# How to hide 'Running in Chrome' toast on TWA application on Android devices?

Tags: android, google-chrome, trusted-web-activity

Few days ago I released an application meeting TWA requirements in PlayStore. Application behaves like a native app, URL bar is of course hidden.

The problem is that application displays native toast 'Running in Chrome' when application is fired for the first time. Users are complaining about that and gave us some bad notes on Google Play.

Is there any possibility to hide this toast?

Answer (score 8):

It it not possible for now.

Look at this source, they put it there with purpose:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=813100

Comment: somehow, it is weird. if they put it there for a purpose, might as well not let users hide the toolbar using digital asset links.